# How to read a JSON file in angular 6

Tags: json, angular6

I created a project using angular cli [ version -  6.1.3 ] and was trying to import a JSON file in the component as -

```
import * as serverJson from '../../config/appdetails.json';
```

I wanted to include the following in the typings.d.ts -

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

However, there is no typings.d.ts present in the project structure.

In such circumstance, what is the best way to import a JSON file in angular 6 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just **create typings.d.ts** in that folder where yours JSON data is stored with this content:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Then you can import your data in this manner, you need to name it, dont  use '*':

```
import appDetails from '../../config/appdetails.json';
```

Comment: @josip you forgot to include declare at the start of d.ts file.
by any chance if you could create plunkr for this solution I guess it will help alot.